# Norm of dual space as sup on the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

In the book "Mathematical Concepts of Quantum Mechanics" (Gustafson and Sigal) the dual space $V^*$ of a vector space V is defined as the set of bounded linear functionals on $V$. The book goes on introducing a norm on $V^*$:

$$ ||f|| = \sup_{x \in V, ||x||=1} | f(x)|. $$

I don't understand how the evaluation of the sup on the unit sphere of $V$ alone can lead to the condition that $||f||=0 \implies f = 0$, where the $0$ function of $V^*$ would be the function mapping every element of $V$ in the $0$ of the complex plane. I can imagine a function that maps the unit sphere of $V$ into $0$ but maps the rest of $V$ into non-zero elements of $\mathbf{C}$, that then would have a zero norm but would differ from from the null function of $V^*$. Am I missing part of the reasoning?

Comment: The function you imagine could not possibly be linear.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How would you show that? Showing that there is a basis of the space V composed of normalised vector?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown or probably better, supposing that there is a vector $x \in V$ whose norm is different from one and $f(x)\neq0$, the vector $y = x/||x||$ would lie on the unit sphere and thus $f(y)=0$. However I'm supposing that f is linear, so $f(x)=f(y*||x||)=||x||*f(y) \neq 0$ which is absurd.

Thanks, your comment helped me figuring out the problem. Maybe you can make it an answer and I'll accept it when I'll be allowed to do so.